# Excel Dropdown list with number result (not text)

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create two dropdown menus in Excel, where one is dependent upon the other. I've found plenty of resources on the internet about this, but none of them seem to work since the dependent list is numbers (1,2,3, etc) rather than text. I was able to make this work with random text, but not with numbers. I also converted the numbers to text, but this didn't work either. Can anyone help me?

[here is a screenshot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKTPR.png)

In this example, a user would select a role in column E (first dropdown) and then the second dropdown would limit users to selecting only levels available to that role.

Comment: See if this helps:  https://superuser.com/questions/223945/custom-validation-dependent-drop-down-lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using VBA the best way to accomplish nested data validation would be with Named Ranges.

It can also be done with a combination of named ranges, custom formatting, and the `INDIRECT()` function.

Without knowing what the expected result is of the table it is difficult to provide an exact answer.

Add numbers 1-5 in a column. Highlight the numbers 1 and 2 and create a named range "Analyst". Highlight 1-4 and type do the same for "Engineer". Repeat until all roles are named in ranges.

Then take your roles in a list, name that range "Roles".

In cell A1 type Role

In cell B1 type Level

In cell A2 apply the data validation for list and have Source: `=Roles`

In cell A2 name the range "Role"

In cell B2 apply the data validation for list and have Source: `=INDIRECT(Role)`

You will then have a number in the drop down list associated with the role.

Edit: I forgot to mention, a named range cannot be only a number, so there are limitations in respect to numeric names.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that the named ranges needed to match exactly what's in the look up list. Thanks!